# asp losing session after FileUpload

Tags: c#, session

When I upload file to my website I loss the session, and the user should login again?
This my code

```
if (FileUploadControl.HasFile) {
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
    string newFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename),
        string.Concat(words[0], DateTime.Now.ToString("_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"),
            Path.GetExtension(filename)));

    Session["login"] = us.Email;
    Session["Id"] = us.Id;

    string location = usDetail.FolderLink.Trim();
    FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(location) + newFileName);
    lblResult.Text = "the file" + newFileName + " has uploaded";

    var dateAndTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var date = dateAndTime.Date;

    var fp = new FileUpoads(usDetail.Id, DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim(),
        location + newFileName, date);

    string f = ConnectionClass.FileUplud(fp);
    lblResult.Text = f;
}
```

Comment: It's because you haven't kept the userId or whatever you authenticate with in a cookie or session or whatever, also this code isnt enough to answer your question, seems to me they are overriding your sessions by passing a value to them.

Comment: Thank you for ur replay, I pass the session values from login page and I received it on page load in upload.aspx which has the fileuploadControl but when I click button upload using above code the file upload uploaded and saved in database but the session lost.